# Compute number of comparisons in quicksort pivoting on median or third

Tags: sorting, median

With a few friends we read the Algorithm Design Manual from Skiena. One of his (chapter 4) exercises asks for the number of comparisons that the quicksort algorithm does (comparing an element to the pivot) in case (a) the median is used as pivot or (b) the one-third element is used as pivot.

(a) pivot on median (the best one can do)

I got this far: the number of comparisons is $T(n)=n + 2T((n-1)/2)\approx n + 2 T(n/2) = \Theta(n\log n)$.

But I think it's also possible to come up with an exact number. Does anybody know how to do that?

(b) I was not able to solve the following: $T(n)=n + T((n-1)/3) + T(2(n-1)/3)$, as I do not know how to solve this with two different T's.
And, also here I would also want to compute an exact number.

I wrote a small program to count the number of comparisons. It roughly looks like pivoting on the median, one-third, or one-tenth are only a constant factor apart, and pivoting on one-third is pretty close to $n\log_2{n}$.

If I'm allowed to paste links, here's my experimental result:
http://postimg.org/image/fr18zahp3/full/

Any help would be greatly appreciated ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the general case (pivoting on third, tenth or other constant fraction), consider the maximum depth quicksort will need to call itself recursively until it gets to an one-element array (which is sorted by definition). In each call, the size of its argument shrinks to at most constant multiple of the original size: $\frac{1}{2}$ in case of median, $\frac{2}{3}$ for the one-thirds approach or $\frac{9}{10}$ in the one-tenth case. Thus, the depth of the recursion is not going to exceed logarithm of the number of elements; the base of this logarithm is reciprocal of the shrinking factor. Obviously, every element of the array is going to be processed at most once at each "depth", so the upper bound on number of comparisons evaluates to $n\log_a n$ (where the base of logarithm is 2, 3, 10, ...).

Thanks to the nice property of logarithms, $\log_a n=(\log_a b)(\log_b n)$, all of these pivoting approaches are going to be within multiplicative factor of each other, belonging to $\Theta(n\log n)$. If you want to find the **exact** number of comparisons, you'll have to be **very** careful with your recurrence: expressions like $T(\frac{n-1}{2})$ don't make sense for even values of $n$.

I'll assume you want to solve the following recurrence in the "median" case: $$T(n)=n+T(\lfloor\frac{n-1}{2}\rfloor)+T(\lceil\frac{n-1}{2}\rceil)$$with initial condition $T(0)=0$. If that is the case, you can get further by considering how deep within the QuickSort recursion will each element be chosen as pivot and thus eliminated (it'll be compared with then-current pivots in all depths up to this one). Clearly, there is one pivot chosen in depth 1, two of them in depth 2, four in depth 4 and so on, all the way until all the sorted array is exhausted. The sum of their depths is then equal to the total number of comparisons. Unless I made a mistake, this results in $T(n)=nL-2^L+L+1$ when $2^{L-1}\leq n<2^L$ (Edit: The $+L$ term was missing originally).

Something similar can be done in the non-balanced cases too, although the calculation will most likely be even messier.

Comment: Thanks for your elaborated answer, it is very useful.

Comment: I tried to plot the function $T(n)=nL-2^L+1$ but it did not match the median... It looks even larger than pivoting on the one-third element.

Then I also did a test with a small example. Suppose that we have $n=5$. At level 1, there are 4 comparisons to the pivot. At level 2, there is two times 1 comparison, and no more at level 3, where the arrays are of size 1 (but maybe you were counting a bit different?)

This gives a total of 6 comparisons, whereas your formula says $T(5)=5L-2^L+1$ and $2^{L-1}\leq 5\leq 2^L, L=3$. Hence, $T(5)=15-8+1=8$.

Comment: You are right; my formula was missing one extra term -- although that one makes the difference from your calculation even bigger. The reason is precisely what I mentioned in the answer -- small differences in the problem setting might affect the exact results quite a bit. Your recurrence suggests there should be $5$ comparisons to pivot performed at level 1 (the $n$ term), plus twice two on level 2 and finally one for each array of size 1 on level 3 (= 11 in total). If you replace $n$ by $(n-1)$ in the recurrence, you'll need to subtract $n$ from my expression; resulting in  $T(5)=6$ too.

Comment: Very cool, thanks. I verified that they are exactly the same now (I should've been more accurate indeed and have used (n-1) among other things). Thanks again.

Comment: Hey, sorry for diggin up an old topic but I have a question regarding your answer. Where does $L$ come from in your solution? I can derive at $nL-2^L + 1$ but do not see why I would need the additional term.

Comment: @Jules Did you use the _exact_ same initial condition $T(0)=0$ and recurrence? My suspicion is an off-by-one difference somewhere, since $nL+L = (n+1)L$, so if your numbers were shifted by one at some point, the extra $L$ could have been absorbed into the first term.

As a simple check, consider $n=1$ (for which we have $L=1$, since $2^0\leq 1<2^1$). The recurrence from my answer gives us $T(1)=1+T(0)+T(0)=1$, while $(nL-2^L+1)$ would be equal to $0$.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, I just do focused on counting the comparisons by consecutively substracting pivots from $nL$, i.e. $nL-(1+2+2^2+...+2^{L-1})$. But is the recurrence ok? T(2) should equal 1, shouldn’t it?